# Terraform: The plugin encountered an error, and failed to respond to the plugin.(*GRPCProvider).ValidateProviderConfig call

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

`The plugin logs may contain more details`

I am trying to deploy an EKS cluster in the eu-central-1 region on aws in terraform.
What am I doing wrong here?
This is my provider:

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "eu-central-1"
}
```

```
❯ terraform validate
╷
│ Error: Plugin did not respond
│
│   with provider["registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws"],
│   on provider.tf line 1, in provider "aws":
│    1: provider "aws" {
│
│ The plugin encountered an error, and failed to respond to the plugin.(*GRPCProvider).ValidateProviderConfig call. The plugin logs may contain more details.
```

Answer (score 13):

I was facing issues related to this in M1 silicon and setting this helped

```
export GODEBUG=asyncpreemptoff=1
```

Related discussion:
https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/27350

Answer (score 8):

It seems that terraform can work very unpredictably with Apple M1 chips:

https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/16948

Jeez, it has been the 5th time that this happened already. If you simply wait 20 minutes and run `terraform init/validate/apply` again, often your problems are solved.
If you face this issue, try it! It works!

Comment: I spam `terraform apply` quickly in succession 3 times , it always works on 3rd time (yes this is ridiculous) `Terraform v1.1.4
on darwin_amd64
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws v3.74.0`

Answer (score 3):

Please, check if you are using Terraform in version X86 instead of version AMD64.

Comment: I downloaded the latest (v1.4.0) but wasn't paying attention to architecture and grabbed x386. Odd thing is it worked on one config/repo, but failed on another one.

Comment: I was running the X86 Windows version on AMD64 machine and got a similar error. Fixed by reinstalling the correct terraform.exe

Answer (score 1):

In case it helps, it worked for me to delete ***.terraform.lock.hcl*** file that is created and run the ***terragrunt init*** command again to recreate the file.

File ***.terraform.lock.hcl*** is created with a new aws-provider version and the error disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

The error was quite annoying and always getting successful after 3-4 runs that too after running terraform init. This can be simply fixed with

export GODEBUG=asyncpreemptoff=1

Answer (score 0):

For me upgrading the terraform client version solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

I have tried changing the terraform.exe to another one worked for me

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).